# Can C be used to capture system calls on a machine?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

Good day,

I was wondering if there is a way to do direct system call capture with C or C++?

I know that currently on unix systems you can use SystemTap to do system capture. The problem I'm having is that in order to feed them into another program for analysis I have to pipe them to the other program.

I'd like to pass things along programatically as this is easier than "printing" out into the pipe and then reading in with the other program.

Is there a way of doing this? How difficult would it be?

Comment: This is highly specific to the operating system. You don't have to look beyond the question title to realize this: "Can C be used to capture **system calls** on a machine?" Of course you can use C or C++, but how that's done is dependent on the OS. So are we talking about Unix only, or do you have another OS in mind?

Comment: At that moment this would only be done on a unix machine. A debian machine to be more precise.

Comment: @Seth, could you point me in the right direction as to how I could go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) does exactly that.

You can take a look at its [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/files/) to see how its done.

Comment: strace captures only the calls of programs that i specify, right? I'm looking for a way to capture all calls that are occurring. ptrace won't let me do this sort of "capture all" type of thing I think, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @Jerry: It would be a security hole if a user-level program could easily intercept syscalls from *all* programs.  But your ptrace-using program can easily intercept syscalls from all its descendants.  Put the program early in your boot or login sequence, and you can get the scope you need.